# Assign an e-mail template to recurring payment with dynamic amounts

Tags: plugins, plugin-charge

`tl;dr;`

How do I tell the webhook callback from Stripe to Charge which template to use for e-mailing the donor when a recurring payment is successfully charged when I don't know what `planAmount` the user will choose?

---

I have a form that I predefine some donation amounts as radio inputs defined as Craft fields...

```
{% set donationAmountOptions = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('donationAmount').settings.options %}

{% set checkedStandard = (charge is defined and charge.planAmount == amt.value)? 'checked' : '' %}
<div class="medium-2 columns float-left">
    <label for="planAmount-{{ amt.value }}">
        <input id="planAmount-{{ amt.value }}" type="radio" value="{{ amt.value }}" name="planAmount" {{ checkedStandard }}>
        <strong>${{ amt.label }}</strong>
    </label>
</div>
```

but then I offer the user an "other amount" number type input where they can define their own donation amount...

```
<label for="planAmount-other-amt">
   <input id="planAmount-other-amt" type="radio" value="{{ (charge is defined ? charge.donationOtherAmount) }}" name="planAmount" {{ (charge is defined and charge.planAmount == charge.donationOtherAmount)? 'checked' }} required class="float-left small-4">
   <span class="float-left small-4">Other Amount</span>
   <input id="otherAmtInput" type="number" value="{{ (charge is defined ? charge.donationOtherAmount) }}" placeholder="0.00" name="fields[donationOtherAmount]" class="float-left small-4">
</label>
```

I use jQuery to assign the value to the accompanying radio input because the radio inputs all have to be called `planAmount` in order for Charge to send the correct amount over to Stripe.

In addition, I give them the ability to decide if that payment will be one-time or recurring on a monthly or yearly basis. Values must be either `<empty>`, `month`, or `year`, in order for Stripe to know what kind of recurring payment to set up.

```
{% set donationRecurrenceOptions = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('donationRecurrence').settings.options %}

<label for="donationRecurrence">
    Donation Recurrence
    <select name="planInterval" id="donationRecurrence" value="{{ (charge is defined ? charge.planInterval) }}" >
    {% for recurrenceOption in donationRecurrenceOptions %}
        <option value="{{ recurrenceOption.value }}">{{ recurrenceOption.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="planIntervalCount" value="0" id="planIntervalCount">
</label>
```

In case anyone comes across this in a similar situation, you **must** have this field above called `planIntervalCount` and it must be set to `1` if there was a recurring interval chosen. I do this through jQuery based on the dropdown choice above.

So far, I have everything working and Stripe will create a new "subscription" (if it doesn't exist) based on the `planInterval` chosen and the `planAmount` that the user either chooses from the radio inputs or the amount that the user inputs in the "other amount" field.

However, here comes the caveat: Since the user can choose their own amount instead of the predefined radio inputs, I don't know how to tell Charge or Stripe which e-mail template to use when a recurring payment gets successfully (or unsuccessfully) charged. I thought I could use this setting below:

```
{% set chargePaymentOptions = { 
   'allowDynamic' : true, 
   'planCurrency': 'usd',
   'actions': {
       'onSuccess':{
              'email':{ 0: 'donation-successful',
                        1: 'admin-donation-notification' },
              'subscription': 'recurring-donation'
        } 
    }
 } %}
```

But then I realized that this is going to assign *everyone* to that subscription. How do I tell the webhook callback from Stripe to Charge which template to use for e-mailing the donor when a recurring payment is successfully charged?

Comment: After deep research into the plugin core code, I have come to the conclusion that the Charge plugin does not have provision to handle this scenario. The only way to do it that I can see is to modify the core plugin code to respond to Stripe API callbacks that the plugin does not have implemented yet.